# how can i increase cpu utilization on a aix unix p5 server

Tags: performance, unix, central-processing-unit, aix, utilization

i need to make cpu utilization increase to about 90%

Answer (score 1):

IBM developer works has stress tools availble for download if you have an account. You could also try out [Stress](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Stress) an open source tool for stressing your system.

> stress is a tool which imposes a configurable amount of CPU, memory, I/O, or disk stress on a POSIX-compliant operating system. It is written in highly-portable ANSI C, and uses the GNU Autotools to compile on a great number of UNIX-like operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

:?
are you sure?
try

```
gzip -c -r / > amicrazy.gz
```

if that doesnt work, just fire another instance :)

i still have few dozens ideas on this if you like...

i bet most users here each have dozens of ways to do this :))

Comment: You probably want to gzip it to /dev/null, so you don't fill / :-P

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to stress test your CPU? then you can compile gcc for example or as mentioned in above answer to zip a large amount of data since this process is CPU intense

However, if you mean you want to get good use out of your box, then you can share the resources of this server using virtualization or by creating LPARs